# mysql subquery where value appears twice or more

Tags: mysql

I have two tables as below (MYSQL)

ENTRY table

```
Event_id |  Horse_id |  Place  
101 101 1  
101 102 2  
101 201 3  
101 301 4  
102 201 2  
103 201 3  
201 101 1  
301 301 2  
401 102 7
```

HORSE table

```
Horse_id    Name  
101   Flash  
102   Star  
201   Boxer  
301   Daisy  
401   Snowy
```

I need to list the horse_id and name of horses that place (1, 2 or 3) two times or more.
best I can come up with which is not near it I know (need to do a subquery)

```
select horse_tbl.horse_id, horse_tbl.name
from horse_tbl
left join entry_tbl 
on horse_tbl.horse_id = entry_tbl.horse_id
where place<4(
select count(horse_id)>1));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your query is on the right track, but instead of using a `WHERE` clause to check the place, you should be using `GROUP BY` along with conditional aggregation in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT
    h.horse_id,
    h.name
FROM horse_tbl h
LEFT JOIN entry_tbl e
    ON h.horse_id = e.horse_id
GROUP BY
    h.horse_id,
    h.name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN e.place IN (1, 2, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 2
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: thanks for the reply Tim. How do the letters h and e work when writing the query. Obviously h is horse_tbl and e is entry_tbl, does this substitute writing the name out?

Comment: Yes, these are table aliases.